# Drupal 7 creating a custom form for content publishing

Tags: drupal

I want to know how I can create a form that will be displayed in any block for publishing content from a specific content type.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you're trying to do ?

Comment: hi @mouhammed , I Just created custom content type and I dont want to use the default form created by drupal available at node/add/mycontenttype , I want create to create a very simplistic form and to be able to put it in a block. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [formblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module and follow these steps :

1. Activate formfblock form module list
2. Go to the admininstration page of the contenttype from which the 'add' form should be made available as a block. Exple : Article
   [image]
3. Go to the 'Form block' section. Check the box "[] Enable data entry from a block" as it says in the description this will 'make the entry form for this content type available as a block.'
   [image]
4. Visit the block administration page to enable and configure the block containing the form.
   [image]
   PS : Only users with permission to create the given content type will see the block. 
   You can also have a look on [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) or [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module if you want more customization.
   Hope that can help you !

Comment: Thank you, I used display suite for the customization